# Are there any Node WebSocket Server javascript client libraries?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm using the node WebSocket Server ( http://static.brandedcode.com/nws-docs/ ) in nodejs for websockets and one java client using this websocket client https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket. I couldn't use socket.io as a server because i couldn't find any java clients for it. Now i've searched for a javascript client for Websocket server, and can't find any. Anyone know of any generic web socket clients in javascript? The socket.io client is not connecting to this server. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> javascript client for Websocket server

It's called [`window.WebSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets/WebSockets_reference/WebSocket).

If you want fallbacks and browser support (The thing socket.io is good at!)

Try

- [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js/)
- [Atmosphere](https://github.com/mmcbride/atmosphere) (A completely different framework)

> I couldn't use socket.io as a server because i couldn't find any java clients for it

Read the socket.io source, write a Java WebSocket client for it. It should only be a thin abstraction ontop of your Java-Websocket.

Personal advice is to make Java support socket.io. Although I don't see why your doing Java - node.js communication over websockets instead of tcp or udp. The latter two are probably better

Comment: Thanks, i found jwebsockets too, and i'm using it now for cross browser fallback. I'll checkout web-socket-js. I just realised could use the browser inbuilt Sockets. Thanks again.

Comment: As raynos said if you want socket.io access in Java,I would probably just use socket.io server written in Java(netty) => https://github.com/ibdknox/socket.io-netty.

Comment: I'm using java as a client, on android actually. I'll probably give writing a java client for socket.io a shot, but a bit later.